# Tensorflow 2.0 freeze_graph failing on tf.keras saved model

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm converting a trained tf.keras model into tf frozen model to use with c++ api. I'm running into error while freezing the model on TF 2.0

```
model_path = '/home/Desktop/model.hdf5'
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
tf.keras.experimental.export_savedmodel(model,newdir)
```

After this a variables folder with files [checkpoint,variables.data-00000-of-00001,variables.index], saved_model.pb and assests folder created in newdir.

I am trying to use saved_model.pb and variables.data-00000-of-00001 files to get single .pb frozen_graph

```
python /home/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py --input_graph=/home/Desktop/tf_models/saved_model.pb --input_checkpoint=/home/Desktop/tf_models/variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001 --output_graph=/home/Desktop/tf_models/frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names=classes --input_binary=true
```

I expected a single frozen .pb file but instead running into error like below:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/home/vsrira10/anaconda2/envs/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 492, in  run_main() File
>   "/home/vsrira10/anaconda2/envs/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 489, in run_main app.run(main=my_main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] +
>   unparsed) File
>   "/home/vsrira10/anaconda2/envs/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 40, in run
>   _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef) File
>   "/home/vsrira10/anaconda2/envs/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py",
>   line 300, in run
>   _run_main(main, args) File "/home/vsrira10/anaconda2/envs/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py",
>   line 251, in _run_main sys.exit(main(argv)) File
>   "/home/vsrira10/anaconda2/envs/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 488, in  my_main = lambda unused_args: main(unused_args, flags)
>   File
>   "/home/vsrira10/anaconda2/envs/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 382, in main flags.saved_model_tags, checkpoint_version) File
>   "/home/vsrira10/anaconda2/envs/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 341, in freeze_graph input_graph_def =
>   _parse_input_graph_proto(input_graph, input_binary) File "/home/vsrira10/anaconda2/envs/tf2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 252, in _parse_input_graph_proto
>   input_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
>   google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message

I'm open to suggestions alternate to using freeze_graph script. Thanks.

Comment: have u got it how to freeze saved_model in tf2? i want to know how, too